# How to Initialize SimpleMembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, database-connection

I want to access full capabilities of [`SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569035%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) such as [`ValidateUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.validateuser%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method.

So according to its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569035%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) I should not call `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` for initialization and instead enable standard membership and role providers.

**My question is:** How can I initialize SimpleMembershipProvider class

**To Finally:** have access to full capabilities of `SimpleMembershipProvider`

or if there is a better solution, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I initialize SimpleMembershipProvider class

If you look at the default ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet application template the AccountController is decorated with the `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` attribute. That's how it is initialized in this sample. This means that you will be able to use it once you have gone through the account controller, not before. If you want to use your membership provider before authenticating you could do the same in your `Application_Start` method.

Comment: Isn't it just a fancy wrapper for `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()`?

Comment: No, it's not. If you look at the source code of this attribute it does much more than just initializing the membership provider. It's also creating the database if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Erm sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean by *all capabilities*? All capabilities compared to what? The classic SQL Membership Provider? If so, then yes, you should not use it but use the classic one.

Comment: @Darin, as IliaG said, it uses it, here: WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

Comment: Yes, and what's the problem?

Comment: @Darin, specificly I mean ValidateUser.. I see it in SimpleMembershipProvider class, but it is not available for use.

Comment: ???? Have you tried `Membership.ValidateUser("username", "secret")`? Why do you want to hardcode this `SimpleMembershipProvider` class in your calling code?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't do anything beyond Blazi already does by calling `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` directly.

Comment: @IliaG, no it does: `((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();` in addition to calling `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` directly.

Comment: @Darin, sorry there is a delay in comments. Shortly I mean: I want to have access to ValidateUser method in SimpleMembershipProvider. If I initialize it with [InitializeSimpleMembership] then I can't use ValidateUser, as mentioned in documentation. So how can I initialize the provider in another way?

Comment: That's just dummy template code. All that does is creating `UserProfile` table, which you would most likely already have.

Comment: Where do you want to call this ValidateUser method? I really don't understand the problem you are encountering. Are you getting some error? Could you show an example of code you have written that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm using it in a WebAPI controller. So one way is adding that attribute before controller. But I shouldn't use that attribute. therefor when I call Membership.ValidateUser("user","secret") in api controller it is uninitialized.

Comment: Alright, then call it in your `Application_Start` method as I already stated in my answer.

Comment: thanks Darin. But if I understand you correctly, you mean use [InitializeSimpleMembership] in Application_Start? If so, then it uses `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` and this shouldn't be done, because this prevents from using ValidateUser..

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I mean call `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` in your Application_Start. What do you mean by `it prevents from using ValidateUser`? Are you encountering some problem with using this method? Are you getting some error?

Comment: Sorry Darin, I think I misunderstood something here, Can you please read the last paragraph of `Remark` section of this documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569035%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I read and know about this remark. This remark is telling you that if you want to use the **full features** of a membership provider you shouldn't be using the SimpleMembershipProvider at all. You should use the classic SQL Membership provider as you were doing for example in ASP.NET MVC 3. But the `ValidateUser` method is perfectly supported and available by the `SimpleMembershipProvider`. So you simply initialize it in your Application_Start method by calling the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` method and then happily use the `Membership.Validate` user method.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to merge the `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` into the `Global.asax.cs` `Application_Start` so that the `SimpleMembershipProvider` would be initialized without any `AccountController` routes being called...

...it could look something like this: http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2013/02/aspnet-mvc-4-membership-users-passwords.html

```
// The using below is needed for "UsersContext" - it will be relative to your project namespace
using MvcApplication1.Models;

using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace MvcApplication1
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }

        private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
        private static object _initializerLock = new object();
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

                try
                {
                    using (var context = new UsersContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }
                    }

                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that post is one of the best "how to's" around.. Thx