# Can't initialize simple membershipprovider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't really know how to identify the problem I currently have.

I want to initialize the simple membership provider but I don't really know how to.

As seen here : [How to Initialize SimpleMembershipProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156835/how-to-initialize-simplemembershipprovider)
I try to add this above my accountController

```
 [InitializeSimpleMembership]
```

The attribute is remaining underligned in red, and when I click on it, I can't "resolve" it.

If I try to add this in my App_Start :

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()
```

It is also underligned in red, and I can't resolve it.

When I add this in my "SignIn" action

```
Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)
```

I'm able to build my app. However, when I try to log in, I get an exception telling me that the SQL server was unreachable.

I've checked the version of System.Web.Mvc in my reference folder : it's version 4.0

Comment: Do you have a reference to `WebMatrix.WebData` in your project?  If not, that's most likely the source of the issue. What does the tooltip say when you hover over the red squiggly line?

Comment: It seems to be the problem. If you add it as an answer, I'll validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SimpleMembershipProvider is contained in the `WebMatrix.WebData` assembly.  You will need to add a reference to this dll (`WebMatrix.WebData.dll`) to your project, and then either the appropriate using/Imports directives:

```
using WebMatrix.WebData; // C#
```

or

```
Imports WebMatrix.WebData ' VB.NET
```

Alternatively, you can fully qualify the class as `WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider` every time you use something from the assembly, but I find it easier to use the using/Imports directives :)